# Converting Calming Animals from GURPS Magic to Dark Ages: Mage

Tags: magic, world-of-darkness, conversion, gurps, dark-ages-mage

As an exercise, I'm trying to adapt spells from **GURPS Magic** (I only have the Brazilian Portuguese version and I don't have any idea of which edition it is, but it seems to be an old one) to **Dark Ages: Mage**. There is a spell named **Calming Animals**. The description is something like that:

> *Allows the operator to calm a single animal. The animal's Reaction check against the operator will receive a bonus equal to twice the energy applied to the spell.*

Ignoring the general rules from GURPS Magic, I wonder if those Pillar ranks would match such effect:

- **Ubbadan:** Al-Fatihah・・
- **Archangels:** Repha-El・・・
- **Seasons:** Autumn・・
- **Forma:** Corona・・・
- **Totems:** Chieftain・・・
- **Runes:** Forlog・・

I'm looking for answers that might confirm that this build is correct or, if it's not the case, what would be the correct build and the logic applied.